# Why GREP can't tolerate multiple \n characters

Tags: regex, bash, grep, multiline

I am trying to use GREP to select multiple-line records from a file.

The records look something like that

```
########## Ligand Number :       1
blab bla bla
bla blab bla


########## Ligand Number :       2
blab bla bla
bla blab bla


########## Ligand Number :       3
bla bla bla


<EOF>
```

I am using Perl RegEx (-P).

To bypass the multiple line limitation in GREP, I use grep -zo. This way, the parser can consume multiple lines and output exactly what I want. generally, it works fine.

However, the problem is that the delimiter here is two empty lines after the end of last record line (three consecutive '\n' characters: one for end line and two for two empty lines).

When I try to use an expression like

```
    grep -Pzo '^########## Ligand Number :\s+\d+.+?\n\n\n' inputFile
```

it returns nothing. It seems that grep can't tolerate consecutive '\n' characters.

Can anybody give an explanation?

P.S. I bypassed it already by translating the '\n' characters to '\a' first, then translating them back. like this following example:

```
    cat inputFile | tr '\n' '\a' | grep -Po '########## Ligand Number :\s+\d+\a.+?\a\a\a' | tr '\a' '\n'
```

But I need to understand **why** couldn't GREP understand the '\n\n\n' pattern.

Comment: Add `(?s)` at the start, or replace `.` with `[\s\S]`. In a PCRE regex, `.` does not match line break symbols by default, and `s` modifier enables the POSIX like dot behavior.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
Please read my question carefully till the end. I am clearly asking "why couldn't GREP understand the '\n\n\n' pattern"?

Comment: Computers cannot "understand" anything. Either the engine matches a string or not. A `.` in a PCRE regex does not match `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a PCRE regex, `.` does not match line break symbols by default, and `s` modifier enables the POSIX like dot behavior.

Thus, add `(?s)` at the start, or replace `.` with `[\s\S]`.

```
(?s)^########## Ligand Number :\s+\d+.+?\n\n\n
```

Comment: You are right. the problem was not parsing the '\n\n\n' pattern, but in parsing/understanding/matching the internal '.' as '\n'.